# How can I show this property about the quantile function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a non-decreasing right continuous function, and it's generalized inverse function $F^{-1}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $F^{-1}(y)=\inf \{x\in \mathbb{R}:F(x)\geq y\}$.

How can I show that if
$F^{-1}$ is continuous at $y$ and if $F(x-)\leq y\leq F(x)$ then $F^{-1}(y)=x$?

Comment: If you take $F$ left continuous, why $F(x-)$ and $F(x)$ differ?

Comment: I edited the post, I meant right continuous, my bad, thank you.